# At the top of my app there is my app name how do I get rid of it?

Tags: android

How do I get rid of the margin at the top with my app name and Icon? 
Here is my SDK versions if you need them
`android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"`

Answer (score 3):

change your Manifest file to :

```
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
```

Note the *android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"*

Answer (score 1):

The bar at the top is called [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). You can either remove it by choosing a theme without an action bar, like `Theme.Holo.NoActionBar` or by calling `getActionBar().hide()` in your activity.